# Yii2 range slider on finish slide event

Tags: jquery, plugins, yii2

I use [this slider plugin](http://demos.krajee.com/slider) and in the documentation writes that I can use these events:

```
pluginEvents = [
"slideStart" => "function() { log("slideStart"); }",
"slide" => "function() { log("slide"); }",
"slideStop" => "function() { log("slideStop"); }",
"slideEnabled" => "function() { log("slideEnabled"); }",
"slideDisabled" => "function() { log("slideDisabled"); }",
];
```

but when I use it:

```
<?
                echo '<b class="badge">3</b> ' . Slider::widget([
                        'name'=>'age',
                        'value'=>'250,650',
                        'sliderColor'=>Slider::TYPE_GREY,
                        'pluginOptions'=>[
                            'min'=>3,
                            'max'=>21,
                            'step'=>1,
                            'range'=>true
                        ],
                        'pluginEvents' => [
                            "slideStop" => "function() { log("slideStop"); }",
                         ],
                    ]) . ' <b class="badge">21</b>';
                ?>
```

it prints an error on pluginEvents `syntax error, unexpected 'slideStop' (T_STRING), expecting ']'`.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

I want to call AJAX function on stopSlide

Answer (score 0):

You are using double quotes inside double quotes here:

```
"function() { log("slideStop"); }"
```

Either escape them like this: `\"` or just use single quotes `'`.

Some other tips:

- Don't use `<?`, use `<?php ?>` or `<?= ?>` instead.
- It's not good practice to put HTML code inside PHP string.
- Use code editor with error highlighting.